# How to delete a row in table which is not present in other table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, delete-row, composite-primary-key

Constraints are :

1. Table has composite Fks.
2. Two tables are identical in structure wise.

I have tried with following way.

**Query :** `delete from fruit where fruit.name and fruit.pos in (select * from fruit except select * from fruit_temp)`

**results :**

> only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an
>   expression: delete from fruit where fruit.name and fruit.pos in
>   (select * from fruit except select * from fruit_temp)

I need to perform the delete operation in table fruit which has rows not in fruit_temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, IN works only with a single column.

To check multiple columns, you need a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
DELETE FROM fruit
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM fruit_temp
                  WHERE fruit_temp.name = fruit.name
                    AND fruit_temp.pos  = fruit.pos );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, as correlated subquery is inefficient when table has huge rows (1000 in number). what would be the best way other that correlated query ? thanks in advance !

Comment: Correlated subqueries are just as efficient as other methods, if there is an index for the lookup columns.